# Cause for vs cause of

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I read this sentence somewhere today, but I think that the *of* would fit better here than *for*, don't you think?

> The cause *for* the original problem will be analysed in the normal maintenance hours.

I find myself sometimes thinking when I should use *for* and *of* and I cannot reach a conclusion. A few guidelines on this subject will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share whatever research effort you have already made so we do not waste effort.

Comment: Looks fine to me. The preposition change just changes the meaning somewhat.

Comment: Could you tell me the meaning for one and for another ?

Comment: MetaEd, in my official language the translation of the preposition *of* make more sense to me than the use of prepositon *for*, but then I see other people use *for* instead of *of*.

Comment: What is your “official language”, and what does this mean? Is this a translation question?

Comment: Probably duplicates one or more of [Justification: *of* or *for*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57462), [“your preference of/for time and venue”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76010/appropriate-preposition-your-preference-of-for-time-and-venue), [“A disliking of” vs. “a disliking for”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67048/a-disliking-of-vs-a-disliking-for),

Comment: Also see [“Of” and “For” Before “-ing”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62633/of-and-for-before-ing),

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cause+for%2Ccause+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) would suggest that *cause for* is not as frequently used as "cause of". "Cause for" seems to mean "a valid reason for", as in "cause for alarm". "Cause of" implies a causal relationship, as in "this is the cause of that".

I personally can't think of many contexts where "cause for" would be appropriate other that "cause for alarm" and phrases similar to it. As Daniel says, similar phrases are "cause for concern", "cause for panic", etc

Comment: No, that's *not* what that NGram "would suggest." In fact, it shows the opposite. The fact that "cause of" beats it in usage doesn't mean that usage of "cause for" is negligible. Look at the values on the Y-axis and then compare them to some truly obscure phrases.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've made the edit, and will be more careful next time.

Comment: That’s a cause for concern, not a cause of concern.

Answer (score 5):

Prepositions don’t necessarily translate one for one. It’s the *problem’s cause*, no matter which way you look at it.

Consider Latin *casus belli*.  That might be translated at *war’s case* or *case for war*.  Notice it is not *case ∗of war*.

Sometimes the English word *for* looks towards the future, and sometimes it looks towards the past.  Here:

> Ya ain’t got no cause for complainin’.

It’s looking towards the future, and is equivalent to *cause to complain* or *cause for complaint*.

But sometimes English *for* looks towards the past.

> There’s gotta be a cause for this mess.  This crap doesn’t happen by accident.

In that situation, *for* is looking in the past, and could be replaced with *behind*.

Other forward-looking examples of *for* include:

> This present is for John.
>   This card is for taking out money from a bank.

Other backward-looking examples of *for* include:

> I did it for my children.
>   I got four quarters for a dollar.

You have to translate by sense, not by exact word. Not all languages support a *for* preposition that has so many different senses as English does.  Two such examples are Spanish and Portuguese, where you must always figure whether in any given phrase, *for=por* or *for=para*.

Comment: Hi tchrist, I'm portuguese thence all this confusion, but I still in doubt about my question, we should *for* or *of* ?

Comment: I don't know if the following results are helpful for (or "to"?) you, however "the cause of the cardiac arrest" has 122,000 hits in Google, while "the cause for the cardiac arrest" has only 8 hits. @utxeee Hence, I would go with "of", but I'm not native of English language.

Comment: @utxeee That’s what I was thinking might be going on here. In that case, you would use *de* or *por*, not *para* here. It’s like when there’s a reason for something or other; you don’t use *para* there.  The mapping between English and Portuguese is not one-to-one here.

Comment: Any reference links on the subject tchrist ?

Comment: @utxeee: I don't know if it is helpful for you the fact that in Italian language is correct to say "la causa _del_ problema ...", while is unusual to say "la causa _per il_ problema ...". Italian and Portuguese have the same origins in the Latin, but English is totally different. Go with "of", no one will say that "of" in your case is wrong.

Comment: @utxeee I’m not sure what you’re asking about, but it is probably offtopic because it involves translation issues.  Certainly you can Google up 5m instances of `"causa por"`, but they are outnumbered 25:1 by `"causa de"`. On the other hand, hits for `"causa por"` do somewhat outnumber `"causa para"`, by about 8.6%. However, that is all misleading in various ways (like partial false positives for Italian, which do not apply here) that are all, again, lamentably offtopic. Just use *de* and don’t worry about the apparent mismatch of prepositions between languages.

Comment: @Carlo_R: Those Google hits for *cause of/for* do indeed reflect overwhelming faithfulness to the idiomatic choice. Check *"understand the cause of/for"* in Google Books, and you'll find a few dozen *"for"*, against hundreds of thousands of *of's*. You can bank that particular idiomatic usage *(bank = add it to your acquisitions),* and probably bank on the method to resolve questions about other usages *(bank **on** = rely upon)*.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Although I may agree with you that *of* is fine in the given sentence, I'd be extra careful not to draw parallels between languages just because they share the same origins. I don't speak Portuguese and so I'm not capable of assessing the degree of similarity/difference between the prepositions utxeee mentions, but in Italian the expression "la causa *per il* problema" is not just unusual, it is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, *cause for* is only felicitous with positive outcomes:

> *His arrival was the cause for much rejoicing*, *great joy*, *unbridled celebration*, ...

As opposed to:

> *His arrival was the cause for much handwringing*, *great panic*, *unbridled flight*, ...

— all of which sound slightly odd and are improved, I feel, by use of *of*:

> *His arrival was the cause of much handwringing*, *great panic*, *unbridled flight*.

That said, I’m not aware of much prescriptivist ink being spilled on this topic, so others may have a different impression of what constitutes standard usage.

Comment: "Cause for alarm"?

Comment: Gesplunn, indeed, you’re right: _cause for alarm/panic/concern_.  Can you think of any others?  I’ll add an edit when I come back...

Comment: "cause for lamentation"

Comment: cause for despair

Comment: I wonder would it be correct to substitute "cause" with "reason" in the "cause for alarm/panic/concern" = "reason for alarm/panic/concern