# Which word fits better in a cause and effect sentence?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity

If there is a sentence-

> English is not too difficult to master, ____ it gets easier and easier
>   with practice

which of these words would be the best fit for the blank and why?

1. So
2. When
3. As
4. Consequently

At the outset, it would appear that "as" seems a good fit here, but when you do think about it, even the other words look like a plausible option. In effect, it closely resembles a "cause and effect" scenario, hence the confusion. Other than "consequently", I think all the other words do fit here, at least in a way.

I did come across a similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76420/cause-for-vs-cause-of), but this didn't help in getting me a certain answer for my question.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: 'and' it gets easier and easier with practice.

Comment: ...therefore it gets easier and easier with practice.

Comment: Your examples mean different things, so you can't say that one is "better" than another.

Comment: "because" creates the most sensible sentence.  it's actually unclear **what you mean**

Comment: None of the options given really make for a very good sentence. _Consequently_ would create a comma splice, so that is especially not recommended. The best option is to insert **nothing at all**, but change the preceding comma to a colon: the fact that practising makes it easier is a kind of explanation of how English is easy to master. The more basic problem, of course, is that it's an inane statement—_every_ language gets easier with practice.

Comment: I'd far prefer a colon and **no** sentence connector here. The second independent clause does not the reason or cause for the statement in the first, but rather restates and enlarges upon it slightly (so 'ie' would make more sense).

Comment: This question may at best be asked on [ell.se]

Comment: @Janus I entirely fail to disagree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options mean different things, so you can't say that one is better than another.

**So/consequently/therefore**: using these would mean that the first phrase is the reason for the second

**Because/as**: using this would mean that the second phrase is the reason for the first

**When**: using this joins the phrases together to mean that English isn't difficult when practising makes it get easier (which is tautological.)

Comment: 'Consequently' would require a semicolon at least.